# jQuery use scrollIntoView() function JS in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

On my WordPress project, I have a form that allows me to display my results at the bottom of the page.

Only I would like that when I load the page I would like to have a scroll that points to an element ID

Looking at the documentation I see that I can use the `scrollIntoView()` function

Which will give something like this :

```
let target = document.getElementById("target");
target.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
```

My `id="target"` points to my section where I have displayed the results after validating my form

```
<section id="target" class="search-results">
   // code
</section>
```

Here is the research :

[image]

my JS function which allows me to reload my page, but I don't know if it's possible to do this

```
    jQuery('form.searchform').on("submit", function(e) {
        var start_time = (jQuery(this).find("#address_start_time").val() != undefined) ? jQuery(this).find("#address_start_time").val() : jQuery(this).find("#start_time").val();
        var start_date = parseDate(jQuery(this).find("#datepicker-adress").val() + " " + start_time);
        var end_time = (jQuery(this).find("#address_end_time").val() != undefined) ? jQuery(this).find("#address_end_time").val() : jQuery(this).find("#end_time").val();
        var end_date = parseDate(jQuery(this).find("#datepicker-adress1").val() + " " + end_time);
        var today = new Date();
        // console.log(start_date);
        // console.log(end_date);
        // console.log(today);
        if(start_date < today){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(ipkdatepicker.error_on_start_date);
        } else if(end_date < today){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(ipkdatepicker.error_on_end_date);
        } else if(end_date < start_date){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(ipkdatepicker.error_on_end_date_from_start);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('button[alt="Search"]').css("display","none");
            jQuery(this).find('button.searchloader').css("display","inline-block");
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                jQuery('form.searchform').find('button[alt="Search"]').css("display","inline-block");
                jQuery('form.searchform').find('button.searchloader').css("display","none");
                let target = document.getElementById("target");
                target.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
            });
        }
    })
```